# How do I lay out views using absolute positioning instead of flex?

Tags: react-native

React native doesn't allow for zIndex and instead suggests layering views based on the order they're rendered in. I have a module on the top half of my screen and one on the bottom, I want the module on top to have a shadow that overlaps the bottom one. In order to achieve this I have to render the bottom half first. Easy enough with absolute positioning right?

My react styles:

```
topContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0, 
    right: 0,
    height: 200,
    backgroundColor: '#cccccc',
    shadowColor: "#000000",
    shadowRadius: 10,
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowOffset: {
      h: 0,
      w: 0
    },
},
bottomContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 100,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#333'
}
```

My JSX:

```
<View>
    <View style={styles.bottomContainer}>
        <ContentView results={this.state.results} />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.topContainer}>
        <SearchBar onSearch={this.onSearch} />
    </View>
</View>
```

But when I do this, the bottomContainer doesn't fill the screen, it conforms to its content. But because of the variety of screen sizes I can't put a definite pixel size for the height and am therefore stuck.

Comment: "But because of the variety of screen sizes I can't put a definite pixel size for the height"


You should be able to fetch the size of the screen and update the style

Answer (score 2):

If you add `{flex: 1}` to the outer `<View>`, then it should fill the screen, as well as the absolutely-positioned components within it.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem though, I need to have the first (visually) element rendered second so it overlaps the second (visually) element. Using flex, the first element is rendered first and second is rendered second.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `elevation` property, this is an android only feature and it can do what you want.

The property description:

> elevation number
>
> (Android-only) Sets the elevation of a view, using Android's
>   underlying elevation API. This adds a drop shadow to the item and
>   affects z-order for overlapping views. Only supported on Android 5.0+,
>   has no effect on earlier versions.

Reference: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html